# Apply tolerance in iterative for loop

Tags: python, numpy, loops, iteration

I have set `p=2` as an initial value and I have calculated `dp` by using the relation. And I want to make an iteration by updating the new `p` value (for first iteration `p1=p+dp1`, the second iteration `P2=P1+dp2` and so on).

I want to stop my loop is the difference between two `dp` value is `0.001` (like `dp2-dp1<0.001`). But I am not able to stop my loop by applying this condition.

I want to know how to apply the tolerance condition to stop the loop. (I don't want to stop with the number of iteration like 10 iterations in my code.)

```
A=0.002
f=10
z=4
p=2
y0=A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
y1= A*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
c=np.sum((yexp-y0)*y1)
d=np.sum((y1)**2)
dp=np.divide(c,d)
#print (dp)

for values in range(10):
    tolerance=0.001
    p+=dp
    y0=A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
    y1= A*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
    c=np.sum((yexp-y0)*y1)
    d=np.sum((y1)**2)
    dp=np.divide(c,d)
    #f = open('c:/Users/USER/Desktop/test/single_freq.txt','')
    print(#os.path.basename(temp),
          dp,
          p,
          sep="\t",
          #file=f
         )
```

Comment: `while dp2-dp1>0.001:` ?

Comment: Are there any mathematial guarantees about the successive values of `dp` ? For example, that the successive values will always be positive ? That the successive values will be in descending order ? Descending order but only in magnitude ? Unless you are sure of some of these guarantees, you can't choose a sensible loop-termination condition.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this kind of program needs a mathematical certificate like the dps tend to zero or is a Cauchy sequence... to ensure that the condition tolerance >=epsilon is eventually fulfilled. You would also need to get some hints of convergence rate, to know how much time it is going to take to terminate.

Comment: dp comes from the optimization of the Gauss-Newton method so It will converge up to many iterations (may diverge in case of some other files). but I want to stop my iteration with tolerance (if different between, dp between two iteration step is less than tolerance i don't want to go forward even if it converge or any case)

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the comments, use a while loop :

```py
A=0.002
f=10
z=4
p=2
y0=A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
y1= A*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
c=np.sum((yexp-y0)*y1)
d=np.sum((y1)**2)
dp=np.divide(c,d)
epsilon = 1
tolerance=0.001
while epsilon > tolerance:  
    p+=dp
    y0=A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
    y1= A*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+p)*np.exp(-z*t)
    c=np.sum((yexp-y0)*y1)
    d=np.sum((y1)**2)
    dp2=np.divide(c,d)
    epsilon = dp2 - dp
    dp = dp2
    print(dp,p)
```

Comment: With this while loop my loop stop in one iteration, even if I change the tolerance value (tolerance=0.0001,0.00001 like this) there is no change in output. I  have hundreds of files and I want to run all file at a time and I want to stop iteration of each file with tolerance then some files may stop after 5 iteration, some files after 8, some files after 14  like this . So my problem is how to find the different between value between each consecutive iteration step. Thank you a lot

Comment: Hi Prakash Gyawali, to make some tests on your code, I need the value for variable `t`